# Is a Kuwait transit visa needed for an Indian passport holder who has a GCC Resident Card?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, transit-visas, kuwait

I'm an Indian passport holder with the KSA work visa for one year. Next month I'm flying from India to Saudi Arabia with a 12 hour of layover at Kuwait Airport. I would like to get out of the airport for two or three hours to visit my family and friends who all are in Kuwait.

I have my GCC resident card with a labour profession.

What are the procedures to get a Kuwait transit visa?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need a transit visa. As a foreign *resident* of a GCC country you still require a visa to leave the airport, or have a transit time of more than 24 hours, only people who are *citizens* of GCC countries are exempt from visas. You are able to obtain the visa at the airport [for KD2](https://kuwaitvisa.com/kuwait-transit-visa/).

> Although citizens of GCC countries can travel to Kuwait visa-free,
>   foreign residents living in GCC countries need a visa to enter Kuwait. ([source](https://kuwaitvisa.com/visa-for-gcc-residents/))

Answer (score 0):

No not if your a permanent resident

Comment: We are looking for quality answers, for visa questions sources to and quotes from official sites are important. Can you edit that in?